# int pointer to float pointer - reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

Following is the code:

```
int a = 1;
int* ptr = &a;
float* p1 = (float*)ptr // or reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr);
cout << *p1 << endl;
```

When I try to print the value pointed by float pointer p1, I get the answer as: 1.4013e-45.
Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: What value did you expect and why?

Comment: I was looking to get "1" as the output.

Comment: The pedantic answer is that this is Undefined Behavior. On paper, literally anything can happen, and you have no control over that.

Comment: [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 0x00000001 represents 1.40129846432e-45

Comment: An `int` is not a `float`. The program [breaks language rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) by looking at an `int` as though it is a `float`. As a result, there are no guarantees of what output you should get.

Comment: `float f = a;` if you want the value assigned to a float. The bits of a float are not at all like the bits of an int.

Comment: Side note: When you see a cast like `(float*)`, you're probably looking at a bug. My general rule of thumb for when I see an unexpected C-Style  cast or `reinterpret_cast` is to examine the code more closely. Usually people do this to make a compiler error go away, not realizing all they've done is move the error from compile-time to runtime.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I had one more doubt: is the same thing applicable for doubles and long double (in place of float) also?

Comment: @KshitijGoel yes, but worse, if you try to cast `int*` to `(long) double*` and then derefference it, you will go out of bounds of the `int`'s memory, since `sizeof(double) > sizeof(int)`.  At least for `float`, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` (usually).

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

You access an object through a pointer that is incompatible with the type of the pointed object, and therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I was looking to get "1" as the output.

To get a float 1, you can static_cast int to float, or simply let the conversion be implicit:

```
float f = a;
std::cout << f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer values used in float or double representations are [denormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) and are converted according to the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).